React Native ethers createRandom is giving warning platform does not support secure random numbers
I am using ethers (6.13.2) in react native (0.75.3) and trying to create a new wallet using the function Wallet.createRandom() and I get the following console warning:
Possible unhandled promise rejection (id: 2):
Error: platform does not support secure
random numbers (operation="randomBytes",
code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=6.13.2)


I was able to fix this by installing react-native-get-random-values (1.11.0) and then adding to my file:
import 'react-native-get-random-values';

